# EF Core кодировка

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

Доброго времени суток!
При знакомстве с .NET EF Core возникла следующая проблема.
При выполнении команды

```
dotnet ef database update
```

Появляется ошибка: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же проблемы с кодировкой встречаются непосредственно в самой программе, когда я хочу добавить что-то в CUI приложении, то кодировка сразу слетает (должно быть "Укажите имя инструмента: "):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя, если просто выводить данные из таблицы БД, то с кодировкой всё в порядке.
Очевидно, что проблема в кодировке, но где её задавать или менять не могу найти...

P.S Файлы migrations имеют кодировку UTF-8.